# Spring Saml not working with latest Spring Security 4.0.0.RELEASE

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

I upgraded Spring Security from 3.2.5.RELEASE to 4.0.0.RELEASE

and I'm getting the following error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:255)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.granite.messaging.webapp.AMFMessageFilter.doFilter(AMFMessageFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:613)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.getFilterProcessesUrl()Ljava/lang/String;
at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator.getSAMLWebSSOProcessingFilterPath(MetadataGenerator.java:533)
at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator.buildSPSSODescriptor(MetadataGenerator.java:288)
at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator.generateMetadata(MetadataGenerator.java:189)
at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.processMetadataInitialization(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:127)
at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:86)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
... 21 more
```

when I look at the source code of `SAMLProcessingFilter` it calls the method `getFilterProcessesUrl()` which used to be defined in its parent class `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` (deprecated) and now it has been removed!

is there a way around this, or I have to wait for spring SAML to upgrade to work with spring-security-4.0.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right it appears that Spring Security SAML is not compatible with Spring Security 4. I logged [SES-161](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SES-161) to have it addressed.

**UPDATE**: As pointed out in the comments. The fix is now released. Updating to Spring Security SAML 1.0.1.RELEASE should allow you to work with Spring Security 4. For example, if you use Maven ensure you have the following in your pom:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

<strike>UPDATE (see newer update above): I have [pushed a fix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/commit/8a0da5f0b67f21beb4c574539bd1e1a88be7ee64) into master. I'm trying to get in contact with the project lead to see if he is alright doing a release. For now the best workaround are to [download the project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/archive/8a0da5f0b67f21beb4c574539bd1e1a88be7ee64.zip) and build it yourself or use the 1.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT builds (i.e. [spring-security-saml2-core](https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/org/springframework/security/extensions/spring-security-saml2-core/1.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/))</strike>

Comment: The Spring SAML release 1.0.1 with support for Spring Security 4 is now available at http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/

Comment: This is the change needed, you need to make sure your version is 1.0.1.RELEASE
  <!-- Apache SAML -->
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
       <scope>compile</scope>
     </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Apache SAML -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```