# Sample Application Compatibility With Latest Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

The Spring Security SAML extension sample application doesn't seem to be compatible with Spring Security 4.2.2 (the latest at the time of this writing). At least not out of the box. Is this due to a compatibility issue between the SAML extension and Spring Security or just something that needs to be tweaked / updated in the sample application?

I've seen this link...

[Spring Saml not working with latest Spring Security 4.0.0.RELEASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29688479/spring-saml-not-working-with-latest-spring-security-4-0-0-release)

...where a commenter says that the SAML extension should be compatible with Spring Security 4, but I can't seem to figure out what changes need to be made to the SAML example application to get it working.  Has anyone else figured this out?

Thanks!